# How to remove the undefined that is added to strings in an array (for no reason, from my knowledge)?

Tags: javascript, string

I have this code, it should work well, but it doesn't and I can't find out why. I also should mention that this does use the [prismjs](https://prismjs.com) library. I customized it to let my created HTML element of codeform to be used like the pre element in the library.

The [prismjs](https://prismjs.com) library has no role in the problem, it is just a syntex highlighter used to format the output.

```js
function codeform123() {
    var cod = document.querySelectorAll("codeform");
    for (let i=0; i < cod.length; i++) {
        var type = cod[i].getAttribute("type");
        var content = cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/||/\r/||/\n\r/||/\r\n/);
        cod[i].innerHTML = "";
        for (let ii=0; ii < content.length; ii++) {
            if (content[ii] != "") {
                var thisLine = content[ii].split("");
                const splited = [];
                var splitedNum = 0;
                var sa = 0;
                var sb = 1;
                var back = 0;
                var iii;
                for (iii=0; iii<thisLine.length; iii++) {
                    if (thisLine[iii] == "undefined" || thisLine[iii] == undefined || thisLine[iii] == null) {continue;}
                    if (thisLine[iii] == " " && back == 0) {
                        splited[sa+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                    } else {
                        if (thisLine[iii] != " " || thisLine[iii+1] != " ") {
                            back = 1;
                            if (iii==0) {
                                sa=1;
                                sb=0;
                            }
                            splited[sb+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                        } else {
                            splitedNum+=2;
                            splited[sa+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                            back = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (iii=0; iii<splited.length; iii++) {
                    if (splited[iii].includes("  ")) {
                        cod[i].innerHTML += splited[iii];
                    } else {
                        var code = document.createElement("code");
                        code.classList = "language-"+type;
                        code.innerHTML = splited[iii];
                        cod[i].appendChild(code);
                    }
                }
                if (ii != (content.length-1)) {cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";}
            } else {
                if (ii != (content.length-1)) {cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";}
            }
        }
    }
}
codeform123();
```

```css
codeform {
    display: block;
    color: #f8f8f2;
    background: #272822;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
    
    text-align: left;
    
    white-space: pre;
    
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;

    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;

    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```

```html
<codeform type="css">#test {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}</codeform>
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, it is returning this:

```
undefined#test {
undefined  undefinedwidth: 1px;
undefined  undefinedheight: 1px;
undefined}
```

However, I would like it to return this:

```
#test {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

So, how do I get it to work the way that I want? As I don't understand where the undefineds come from. I believe the problem is when the strings are reconstructed into the array splited. As I have looked at the thisLine array and have seen that there are no undefineds, so where do they come from?

It should be noted that I have tried using `.slice()` and yes it did work when I placed them where the strings are added back to the codeform element. When I did add them, the code snippet would look like this:

```js
function codeform123() {
    var cod = document.querySelectorAll("codeform");
    for (let i=0; i < cod.length; i++) {
        var type = cod[i].getAttribute("type");
        var content = cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/||/\r/||/\n\r/||/\r\n/);
        cod[i].innerHTML = "";
        for (let ii=0; ii < content.length; ii++) {
            if (content[ii] != "") {
                var thisLine = content[ii].split("");
                const splited = [];
                var splitedNum = 0;
                var sa = 0;
                var sb = 1;
                var back = 0;
                var iii;
                for (iii=0; iii<thisLine.length; iii++) {
                    if (thisLine[iii] == "undefined" || thisLine[iii] == undefined || thisLine[iii] == null) {continue;}
                    if (thisLine[iii] == " " && back == 0) {
                        splited[sa+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                    } else {
                        if (thisLine[iii] != " " || thisLine[iii+1] != " ") {
                            back = 1;
                            if (iii==0) {
                                sa=1;
                                sb=0;
                            }
                            splited[sb+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                        } else {
                            splitedNum+=2;
                            splited[sa+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii];
                            back = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (iii=0; iii<splited.length; iii++) {
                    if (splited[iii].includes("  ")) {
                        cod[i].innerHTML += splited[iii].slice(9);
                    } else {
                        var code = document.createElement("code");
                        code.classList = "language-"+type;
                        code.innerHTML = splited[iii].slice(9);
                        cod[i].appendChild(code);
                    }
                }
                if (ii != (content.length-1)) {cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";}
            } else {
                if (ii != (content.length-1)) {cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";}
            }
        }
    }
}
codeform123();
```

```css
codeform {
    display: block;
    color: #f8f8f2;
    background: #272822;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
    
    text-align: left;
    
    white-space: pre;
    
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;

    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;

    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```

```html
<codeform type="css">#test {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}</codeform>
```

In this second code snippet, it does what I want, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, meaning fixing the problem without using `.slice()` right before the string is added back into the codeform element.

Comment: "So, how do I get it to work the way I want?" - you haven't mentioned what you are trying to accomplish with this code. i will say that you appear to be trying to add to undefined array items with lines like this: `splited[sa+splitedNum] += thisLine[iii]`. you can't add to undefined. there are other problems with this code, but we'll start there.

Comment: @dqhendricks What I am trying to accomplish is to make a tag, what I'm trying to accomplish can be complicated for me to explain, but one thing is that I am trying to learn new things. As like I stated I'm trying to find a way to keep undefined from appearing in the strings that are returned when the undefined is not wanted, meaning when undefined wasn't in the original strings.

Comment: "trying to make a tag" is pretty vague and unhelpful. can you elaborate? I believe undefined is part of your string because of the issue I mentioned above. did you understand what I was saying there? `splited[sa+splitedNum]` is undefined when you first add characters to it, so your code is likely converting the undefined variable into a string 'undefined' as you add those characters to it. You can't use `+=` on a variable until you first define it. You can define the array item by first assigning a value to it, whether that be a blank string, or whatever.

Comment: @dqhendricks Yeah I understood, I've fixed it with placing `splited.push('')` before `splited[sa+splitedNum]` is called. I should have realized that I was trying to add content to array items that yet to have been created. I was being a little stupid.

Comment: everyone's gotta start somewhere. sounds like you understand, which means you're doing pretty good. keep it up. you got this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very hard to follow, but I suspect that the `splitedNum += 2` line is the problem because it risks creating an array with holes, and the holes will end up showing up as `undefined`. But I can't say I understand what your code is doing.

There is also several problems in your code, for instance:

```
cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/||/\r/||/\n\r/||/\r\n/)
```

and

```
cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";
```

do not do what you think they do.

```
if (content != "")
```

is always true as `content` is an array.

```
if (thisLine[iii] == "undefined" || thisLine[iii] == undefined || thisLine[iii] == null)
```

All those make no sense because `thisLine[iii]` is a one-character string.

Comment: With `if (content != "")` I forgot to add the `[ii]` to the thing, so it should be `if (content[ii] != "")`. Also, the `splitedNum += 2` is not a problem, the way that my code is set up would not make it have a risk of creating an array with holes. Look at the fact that the statements that use them also have another value that is either a one or a zero, the `splitedNum += 2` is to prevent adding something that shouldn't be in that array item. Also, I did do testing and have yet to come across a problem with `splitedNum += 2`.

Comment: Can you give more details on the stuff you've stated? Like what `cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/||/\r/||/\n\r/||/\r\n/)` and `cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";` are actually doing.

Comment: The expression `a || b` evaluates to `a` if it is truthy, or to `b` otherwise. Objects and non empty strings are always truthy, so those two lines do exactly the same thing as `cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/)` and `cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"`.

Comment: Ohh, so, `cod[i].innerHTML += "\n"||"\r"||"\n\r"||"\r\n";` the `"\n"` would always return truthy as it is a string, correct? There for, it would be the same with `cod[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/||/\r/||/\n\r/||/\r\n/)` the `/\n/` would always return truthy, correct?